# How to identify button click in getChildView of ExpandableListView in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, baseadapter

I am building ExpandableListView in my android app. I have made child xml layout that repeats upto specific numbers. I have a Delete Button in my xml layout with id set in xml as btnDelete. By clicking delete button I want to delete specific child.

e.g:

Group:

```
Child 1         Delete
Child 2         Delete
Chile 3         Delete
```

Now my problem is that how to identify that which child delete button is clicked. As all delete buttons have same ID in my xml layout. Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your adapter, where you inflate your row layout, you can set a tag (with the `setTag ()` method) to each delete button. The tag can be the row position that this delete button corresponds to.

Later, when someone clicks the button, in the `onClickListener`, you get the button tag (with `v.getTag ()`), parse it to integer and delete the row at that position.

Comment: Thanks Yeah. I was completely unaware of the use of setTag() and getTag() :)

Comment: @Shade How can receive Group position in this case !! Any suggestion ?